# I would like to bare open my Canon D-SLR. Which tools should I buy and use in order to get the best results?

Tags: canon-550d, body, repair, diy, canon-5d-mark-ii

By best results, I mean, not damaging the tiny screws or any other fragile part of the camera.

I would like to be able to open it, and then close it again.

Comment: From my experience servicing a 50D, review the entire procedure on video first (youtube has some), just to have an idea where the screws are hidden, and which element to take off before the other.

Comment: Dare I ask why you would want to do this?!?

Comment: @Mike: because I don't want to let someone charge me a huge amount of money for a repair I can do myself. And I am comfortable with these kind of things. Like completely opening an iPhone, changing its battery and putting it together again.

Comment: @Berzemus: thanks for the advice. By the way, maybe I should make a video of my opening the camera :)

Comment: @SkippyFastol You know there s a slot in the bottom to change the battery and SD cards :P Why do you want to open cam body ?

Comment: @kantu: Who said I wanted to change the battery / SD card ? :-/

Comment: @SkippyFastol Just kiddin ! I just want to know why you want to dismantle it ? Last time I dismantled one dslr but it was already broken and apart from sensor I coudlnt find anything to fiddle around with.

Comment: @kantu: In fact I want to dismantle it to clean up the rear screen ;-). I would like to dismantle it because the rear "fast dial" round button does not work anymore, despite the "lock" button being on OFF.

Comment: PS: it's better if you post answer-like updates to your own question as answers or comments, rather than editing the question. No big deal; just a suggestion.

Comment: @mattdm: Ok ! I had seen that done on other posts... I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/should-edits-which-add-the-accepted-answer-to-the-question-be-reverted — basically, it's a thing people are used to from bb-style forums where their software isn't really meant for QA. Here, it's better not to do it, but habits develop and all that. :)

Comment: @mattdm: You definitely are a hardcore stack overflow user. In other words, a HCSOU ! Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Heh. Is there a badge for that? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4812/discussion-between-skippy-fastol-and-mattdm)

Answer (score 4):

I have done this a few times with other canons, not the 7D though, my question to you is are you comfortable with micro assembly, very fragile connectors, documenting your take down etc?

Typically they use small Philips and some specialized ones as well [take a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives) for a visual guide.

Their are other issues, such as needing a special pry tool *you can fake it but it's tricky*, adhesives, some of which requires heat and some must just be carefully pried loose, and the order that things should be removed in is not always obvious so takes lots of pictures and label screws.

If you speak chinese this might [help](http://vimeo.com/15883496) lol, of course you can just watch and infer what they are doing (might be an english version but I didn't find one)

I would suggest taking it to a tech unless you are already very good at this kind of thing.

Comment: I am totally comfortable with all fo this, excep the heating stuff... I am used to opening and closing iPhones up to the battery stuck to the bottom rear and replacing the mike and dock connector. I guess this will be similar in complexity, but just with more stages. Right ?  :)

Comment: @SkippyFastol - yes a lot more stages, it can at times be puzzling as well they like to hide screws under very thin external overlays etc. It's very easy to forget which screw went where, how things were oriented, order of assembly, connectors sometimes have micro tabs that need to be pressed etc. Just go slow, mark all screws/fasteners and take pictures of everything before you remove it.

Comment: well, nowadays, one can film oneself unscrewing the device, and then play back the movie in reverse... No more need to write things down. But thanks for mentioning the various pitfalls !

Comment: @SkippyFastol, true, but that didn't work so well for me because I have a tendency to forget the camera is there. Anyway good luck *hey publish the video if you make one!*

Comment: I will publish the damn video. I found nice boxes of screwdrivers on iFixit ( there there : http://www.ifixit.com/Parts-Store )

Comment: @SkippyFastol - nice kit

Answer (score 3):

Found this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOb55J09wbU

Seems that unlike iPhones, not so many screwdrivers are needed !

And I think I'll ask the incoming questions here :

http://camera-repair.co.uk/ (I am not a sponsor !)

**EDIT :** Photos of the damn EOS 7 being torn down (as far as I needed to!)

[image]

[image]

DISCLAIMER

That was **NOT** easy, and I had special tools to open the beast. Also, doing this leaves traces on the screws. It will be obvious the camera has been broken into. **DO NOT DO IT ON YOUR OWN. BRING THE CAMERA TO AN AFFILIATED CANON REPAIR GUY.**